# Add totals to the Tax Details Report

Tags: acumatica

On the Tax Details report (TX620500), what is the best way to:
1. Add the Total Sales column to the left of the “Taxable Amt” field
2. Then add subtotals at the bottom all three columns (Total Sales, Taxable Amt, Total Tax) I have tried numerous different ways with zero success.

**Here are some things I have tried:**

1. To add the total sales column: 
I added a text box in the details section 1 and changed the value to =Sum(ARTran.CuryTranAmt) - that didn't work. I am not looking for a count, but that is what this seems to be giving me.

- I added a text box in the details section 1 and changed the value to =[ARTran.CuryTranAmt]- that didn't work (same issue with the count)

2. To add the subtotals: I added a text box in the page footer (also tried report footer) and changed the value to the following three fields (one for each that I need totals for):
      
**=Sum(RowTaxDetailReport.TaxRate)
     
 =Sum(ARTran.CuryTranAmt)
      
=Sum(RowTaxDetailReport.ReportTaxableAmt)**


The report takes forever to run with these changes. Then, numerous lines are repeated at the end. This shouldn't be too difficult, but maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Please EDIT your question and detail what ways you've already tried. Without that information people are likely to make the same suggestions which will waste their time and yours...  Please also refer to the information in the Help center on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would add a Variable at the Details level let's say TaxableTotal.
Then have it's value be = $TaxableTotal + [ARTran.CuryTranAmt]

Then at the footer of the group, enter =TaxableTotal to get your total.
And repeat for the other fields you need to sum up

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Gavin. I have a couple questions of clarification for you:  
1. Instead of my =Sum(ARTran.CuryTranAmt), should I just use =[ARTran.CuryTranAmt] ?
2. There already exists a similar variable within the out of the box report (it's called TaxableTot) and the out of the box report uses this at the footer of the group: =$TaxableTot. The question is, do i need to delete this one or what? Also, wouldn't this just give me the line total (instead of totaling all of these at the bottom of the report?)

Comment: Hi Kyle, the above suggestion will mainly apply to the footer sections. For the lines you can use [ARTran.CuryTranAmt] (I am guessing this is to show the Invoice total against that line.

Comment: Also remember to use module and tran type when linking the ARInvoice/ARTran tables and be careful with ARTran.CuryTranAmt, not sure if you want it instead of ARTran.TranAmt because the taxes are displayed in your base currency but CuryTranAmt will give you the total in the document currency.